# How does mercurial work without Python installed?

Tags: python, mercurial, ironpython

I have Mercurial 1.3 installed on my Windows 7 machine. I don't have python installed, but Mercurial seems to be OK with that.

How does it work?

Also, is it possible to force Mercurial run on IronPython  and will it be compatible?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure if you will see this: I commented on Martin's post to point to discussion of Mercurial on the IronPython list.  As of May they seem to have *some* features working, though definitely not all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Mercurial windows installer is packaged using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). This places the python interpreter as a DLL inside of a file called "library.zip".

On my machine, it is placed in "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\library.zip"

This zip file also contains the python libraries that are required by mercurial.

For a detailed description of how mercurial is packaged for windows, see the developer page describing [building windows installer](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BuildingWindowsInstaller).

Answer (score 7):

Since there is a "library.zip"(9MB), Mercurial's Windows binary package maybe made by [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), py2exe  is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation.

Answer (score 6):

Others have answered the first question -- let me give a guess about the second part.

Mercurial will normally use some C extensions for speed. You cannot use those with IronPython.

But we also ship pure Python versions of these modules, and depending on how much IronPython implements of a standard Python 2.4 environment, those modules could be compatible. I have seen reports on IRC about Jython (the Java port of Python) being able to do a few operations using the pure modules. You should download Mercurial and take a look at the `mercurial/pure` folder. These modules simply has to be moved up one directory level to be found, the `setup.py` script can do this if you pass the `--pure` flag. Please see its source or come talk with us on the Mercurial mailinglist/IRC.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I've already tried it, and found that Mercurial does not work with IronPython. It fails somewhere in OS interaction files.

Comment: Valentin: The most recent discussion on the IronPython list on this topic is from May. They report several features working, but not quite all of them: http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2009-May/010200.html.  Notably this is with the *development* IronPython 2.6.

Answer (score 3):

Mercurial bundles the necessary python binaries within it, I believe.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any python binaries there. Also, Mercurial should use (I presume) Python standard library, so it should be present there as well, but I didn't find it either.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "within", I didn't mean "in the directory", I meant that the executable(s) for Mercurial actually bundle the Python engine within the executable, it's built-in.

Comment: the hg.exe is only 17KB, but there is a library.zip (9MB), which can't be opened by WinZip, can all the prereqs be there?

Comment: Look for a pythonXX.dll in the same directory as library.zip (where XX are numbers).